# Almquist shell last key pressed

Tags: unix, sh

I'm trying to do a fancy-shmancy tweak in my Tiny Core Linux command line. I decorated my PS1 like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEBx2.jpg

But here is what I get in most cases:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FN4dv.png

If I press Tab or Up\Down to scroll history it prints new PS1 strings on top of previous. On the other hand when I press Enter to run a command it prints a new line and it's all OK.
I'm running the `Almquist shell` (ash, *not bash*).
Can I implement the next algorithm:

**1.** If the last key pressed was Enter, then... *(do nothing)*
**2.** Else if the last key pressed was another key, then... *(position the text pointer one line up to redraw the previous PS1.)*

I would implement this right inside the PS1 definition. **But how can I get the last key pressed before some action (when the PS1 is printed) using only `ash` variables and commands?**

Comment: $SHELL = /bin/sh -> busybox

Comment: I believe that I'm using ash, not bourne shell. There is .ashrc in my home folder. And it is said that 'is a lightweight Unix shell originally written by Kenneth Almquist in the late 1980s. Initially a clone of the System V.4 variant of the Bourne shell, it replaced the original Bourne shell in the BSD versions of Unix released in the early 1990s. Derivative versions of ash are still installed as the default shell (/bin/sh)'.

Comment: "Ash is also fairly popular in embedded Linux systems; its code was incorporated into the BusyBox catch-all executable often employed in this area." <-- Yeah, sounds reasonable.